# clicking in a button do nothing in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component which will return a button element, and the onClick handler will dispatch a redux action:

This is the button component :

```
const UxMenuButton = ({children, currentView, defaultTab = false, imgUrl = null, onClick, type = 'submit'}) => {
  return (
    <button className={`ux-btn btn btn-default btn-lg ${defaultTab ? 'apply-dashed' : ''}`} onClick={() => onClick('300')} style={colorSwitcher(currentView)} type={type}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Now the problem is when I click in this `button`, the nothing happens, the button seem to be not clickable at all, and when I fire the `onClick` function outside of the return I can clearly see the state changes in the redux dev tools, it means that the problem comes from the button not firing the `onClick` handler, What I'm missing here ?

The parent component looks like this :

```
  {item.tabs.map((tab, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index + 25} className="col-md-3 text-center">
        <UxMenuButton onClick={changeTopPosition}>{tab.id}</UxMenuButton>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

And this is the onClick fucntion :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({changeTopPosition: (top) => dispatch(menuActions.changeTopPosition(top))})
```

Which call this action creator :

```
export const menuActions = {
    CHANGE_TOP_POSITION: 'CHANGE_TOP_POSITION',

    changeTopPosition: data => ({
        type: menuActions.CHANGE_TOP_POSITION,
        payload: data,
    }),
};
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `onClick` isn't firing by putting a `console.log` in that function? Can you also share the `onClick` function?

Comment: yes this is the problem when I do fire onClick('stufff') outside the return it does the job and I see my state changes in redux dev tools, so the problems comes from the button not being clicked

Comment: Are you doing `e.preventDefault();` in the function? Where `e` is the first parameter to represent the event. `onClick={(e) => onClick(e, '300')})`

Comment: i'm not using preventDefault anywhere.

Comment: Can we see the `changeTopPosition` function?

Comment: updated my question (it's complicated to share code from a redux app :/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148529/discussion-between-glitch100-and-tba3bi3).

Comment: like @Glitch100 said, should it be `onClick= {(e) => changeTopPosition}`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you  missing ****onClick**** function. You can rewrite like this :

```
const UxMenuButton = ({
  children,
  currentView,
  defaultTab = false,
  imgUrl = null,
  onClick,
  type = 'submit'
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`ux-btn btn btn-default btn-lg ${defaultTab ? 'apply-dashed' : ''}`}
      onClick={() => onClick('300')}
      style={colorSwitcher(currentView)}
      type={type}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

`const mapDispatchToProps = {onClick` : **your function for onClick** `}`

```
//final export your component with <b>connect</b> of <b>Redux</b>

export default connect (
   null, mapDispatchToProps) (UxMenuButton )
```

I hope , it will help you  :)